# How to use postgreSQL in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, homestead

I can do migration to my homestead.
this is my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=54320
DB_DATABASE=intern
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

And I make a new server in my **postgreSQL** with

```
server name = Homestead,  
username = homestead,  
password = secret.
```

then, I did migration and all the table created into my database(*server=homestead*)
The problem is, when I want to do login in my site. It occurs an error:

```LogFile
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused↵  
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting↵  
TCP/IP connections on port 54320?↵could not connect to server: Connection refused↵  
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting↵  
TCP/IP connections on port 54320? (SQL: select * from "users" where "email" = user@gmail.com limit
```

Comment: the default database name is `homestead` and try running it from the vagrant box (`vagrant ssh`)

Comment: I have tried, but still get an error.. It works in mysql, but not in my postgresql @morph

Comment: are you able to connect to pgsql server via command line or some gui application?

Comment: I can connect it via cmd, and I can connect via gui application, but when I do `select * from users`. It will load(non stop)@morph

Comment: ensure you have latest version of Vagrant, VirtualBox & Homestead. You may need to destroy your box. Could also try creating a fresh laravel project.

Comment: Have you tried killing your box and restarting it?

Comment: Did you do `psql -U homestead -h localhost intern` and then typed: `secret`?

Comment: yes, I can login into my postgresql.. but I can't insert anything in my table database

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the port to 5432 in the `.env`?

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra 0 at the end of your port. Change `DB_PORT=54320` to `DB_PORT=5432`

Comment: I ever tried it, but same.. 
I think that every homestead should add `0` in the last of port.. like mysql `3306` to `33060` and psql `5432` to `54320`

Comment: do you also specify the port via command line? try to use `5432` and change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I have tried it,, if I am using port 5432.. it works, because it does not using homestead.. I have seen the documentation that there is written to use 54320 @Razor

Comment: you can use both 5432 and 54320, it just depends on your current machine. If you're in the `guest` machine (homestead) you should use the port 5432, if you're in the `host` machine, you should use 54320, otherwise it won't work. Laravel uses the default port 5432 because it's running - by default - inside the guest machine, I'm pretty sure you have to keep it to 5432. Did you try to change `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: Don't forget to restart the server everytime you change the `.env`!

Comment: I have restarted, but the result is same

Answer (score 1):

try to access your homestead with ssh.

i think u already change the password from the inside

from laravel documentation i think that config should work

or try this command after u change the config

`php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan cache:clear`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead#connecting-to-databases